# How do I link RSSReader component with a URL in codename one

Tags: java, rss, codenameone, rss-reader

I tried the following code but it doesn't show anything:

```
@Override
protected void postNews(Form f) {
    RSSReader rss = findRSSRead();
    rss.setURL("http://www.enca.com/rss/world");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the question stated, RSSReader is a component in [Codename one](https://www.codenameone.com). Which means you have to add it to your form for you to see it.

```
@Override
protected void postNews(Form f) {
    RSSReader rss = findRSSRead();
    rss.setURL("http://www.enca.com/rss/world");
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, rss);
    f.revalidate();
}
```